# Nignx try files in different directories for different locations

Tags: nginx, configuration, fastcgi

I have an webapp that uses FastCGI. This app is deployed as different "sites". I have a general nginx configuration for the app, and then, I include upstrams and locations files for each site. Each site needs some .js and .css files. Right now, I have set these via the `root` of the general configuration file. My requirment now, is that I want to be able to use different .css and .js for different sites. So the lookup of the files, should first start at the site/location level and if not found, then search in the general `root`.

The general nginx conf file is:

```
    # Change this directory depending on the server
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/app/upstreams/*.conf;


    server
      {
        server_name 24.39.17.76;

        root /var/www/app/files/;

        listen       443;
        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate   /etc/nginx/conf.d/app/ssl/new/app.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/conf.d/app/ssl/new/app.com.key;

        location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|woff|ttf)$ {

            access_log off; # this is because otherwise, with jail2ban the user may be banned
            # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header Pragma public;

        }

        # Change this directory depending on the server
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/app/locations/*.conf;

      }
```

Note the lines where I include all locations conf and upstreams files.

Then a particular site, has a upstream file like:

```
    upstream siteX
    {
    server localhost:9021;
    server localhost:9022;
    server localhost:9023;
    }
```

And a location file like this one:

```
location ~ ^/siteX/reps {

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/app/siteX_reps_access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/app/siteX_reps_error info;
            if ($arg_service = "true") {
                    rewrite  ^/(.*)$ /service/$1 last;
            }
        rewrite ^/siteX/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri @fastcgiSiteX;

    }


    location @fastcgiSiteX {

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args;
        fastcgi_pass fastcgiSiteX;
        fastcgi_next_upstream error invalid_header http_500;

    }
```

The html of my webpage that includes the css and js is like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/JQDevelopmentLibrary/jQuery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/TBSDevelopmentLibrary/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

But I can easily add a prefix if that helps with any possible solution, like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/siteX/webfiles/JQDevelopmentLibrary/jQuery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/siteX/webfiles/TBSDevelopmentLibrary/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

SO...the general files are under /var/www/app/files/. However, I would like that for siteX, the files are first searched in another path, say /var/www/siteX/files and only if not found, searched in the general one.

One solution I tried but didn't work is to define this `try_files` expression:

```
  try_files /siteX/webfiles$uri $uri @fastcgiSiteX;
```

And then, I put all the folders and files in $document_root/siteX/webfiles, that is,  `/var/www/app/files/siteX/webfiles/`. I thought this solution should work, but it didn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

its kind of a hack but it can be done.

```
location ~ ^/siteX/reps {

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/app/siteX_reps_access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/app/siteX_reps_error info;
            if ($arg_service = "true") {
                    rewrite  ^/(.*)$ /service/$1 last;
            }
        rewrite ^/siteX/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri @hack;

    }

     location @hack {
     root  /var/www/siteX/files;
     try_files $uri $uri/ @fastcgiSiteX;
     }

    location @fastcgiSiteX {

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args;
        fastcgi_pass fastcgiSiteX;
        fastcgi_next_upstream error invalid_header http_500;

    }
```

Comment: Hi. I am trying this solution but I have a question. `try_files $uri @hack;` will try files on $uri and that will be found in my case. Then it will fallback to @hack. I need the other way around, first do a try_files with ` /var/www/siteX/files` and if not found, fall back to ` /var/www/app/files/`. Any ideas how can I adapt your solution? Thanks